# CentOS 7: how/where does one get multilog or s6-log or similar logging program?

Tags: logging, daemontools

On a CentOS 7.8 server, I have a homegrown script that, among other things, starts another program whose output log I need to manage.  I would like to use [`s6-log`](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) or [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html) or [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8) or similar logging program, but cannot seem to find a distribution in the standard CentOS 7.8 or EPEL repositories. A `yum search` for any of them, or for the parent packages such as `daemontools` or `perp` or `s6` or similar turns up empty.

Where *does* one find them? Or is it necessary to build from sources?

I don't need a particular one, just any robust piped logging tool that handles log rotation for output produced by a program or shell script.  It can be one of the ones above or a similar one.  I'm puzzled that none of them seem to be easily found, which makes me think I'm looking for the wrong thing or doing something dumb ...

Comment: systemd can already log to wherever you want. And of course there is already logrotate.

Comment: Unfortunately, using logrotate has the issue that the program producing the output has to have the ability to redirect its output to a new file. Logrotate is what I'm using now and the combination fails for this reason – logrotate moves the files but the program doesn't know it. Programs like `multilog` avoid that issue altogether, which is why I'm trying to use that instead of logrotate. Regarding systemd, I'm not sure what its relevance is for this situation. Could you explain?